# What does it mean/imply that all my singular values are ones?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, svd

Suppose I apply SVD (singular value decomposition) on some real-valued matrix $M$, that is, $M = USV^T$. Now, if $S$ is an identity matrix, what does it mean? Does $M$ have some special properties? Could SVD be then calculated in some peculiar (faster) way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Recall that the singular values of a real matrix $M$ are precisely the eigenvalues of the positive-semidefinite real matrix $M^T M$. Then the singular values of $M$ are all $1$ if and only if the eigenvalues of $M^T M$ are all $1$, if and only if $M^T M = 1$, if and only if $M$ is orthogonal.

EDIT: As Vedran Šego points out, there is, of course, a more straightforward way:

On the one hand, if the singular values of $M$ are all $1$, then any singular value decomposition $M = USV^T$ of $M$ will have $S = 1$, so that $M = UV^T$ is a product of orthogonal matrices, and thus orthogonal. On the other hand, if $M$ is orthogonal, then $M^T M =1$, so that the singular values of $M$ are all $1$.

EDIT 2: And as Memming points out, if $M$ is orthogonal, then $M = M \vec1 I^T$ is trivially a singular value decomposition of $M$.

Comment: Isn't it easier to notice that $I$ is orthogonal and that the product of three orthogonal matrices $($U$, $\Sigma = I$, and $V^T$) is still orthogonal? :-)

Comment: You're absolutely right! Alas, I couldn't help going for the if and only if...

Comment: and hence any orthonormal matrices would be it's SVD?

Comment: @Memming Indeed it is!

Comment: A minor generalization: if (and only if) all singular values are equal, then $M = \sigma U$, where $U$ is orthogonal and $\sigma \ge 0$ is that singular value, and one of its SVDs is $M = U (\sigma I) I^T$.

Comment: Isn't $M$ only semi-orthogonal, since it is not necessarily a square matrix?