# What does it imply that all of the singular values are 1s and 0s?

Tags: linear-algebra, singular-values

These were the two links I looked at:

[What does it mean/imply that all my singular values are ones?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465206/what-does-it-mean-imply-that-all-my-singular-values-are-ones)

[If the singular values of an $n{\times}n$ matrix $A$ are all $1$, is $A$ necessarily orthogonal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3222543/if-the-singular-values-of-an-n-timesn-matrix-a-are-all-1-is-a-necessa)

and I understood how such matrices are necessarily orthogonal. However, what if the singular values are 0's and 1's of a square, real matrix? What does that imply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A matrix $A$ will have singular values all equal to $0$ or $1$ if and only if it is a [partial isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_isometry).

Another characterization is that $A$ has singular values $1$ with multiplicity $r$ and $0$ with multiplicity $n-r$ if and only if there exist matrices $U$ and $V$ with mutually orthonormal columns such that $A = UV^T$.